# How do I set a marker in MapView of React Native

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

- I want to set a marker on MapView in React Native, but I can't find any information through official documents of [MapView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html#content).
- If it is not allowed in that way, how can I use existed react module such as [react-googlemaps](https://github.com/pieterv/react-googlemaps) in React Native?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set markers using the [`annotations` prop.](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

For example:

```
var markers = [
  {
    latitude: 45.65,
    longitude: -78.90,
    title: 'Foo Place',
    subtitle: '1234 Foo Drive'
  }
];

<MapView
  region={...}
  annotations={markers}
/>
```

Comment: @ivanwang Let me know if it works out for you.  If it does, could you mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @naoufal - Any news to whether this works on android?

Comment: you can pass `<Marker>` as `children`, but the [`annotations` prop is not available anymore](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

Comment: This solution is not correct anymore. On the given and valid documentation, there are no "annotations" prop.

Answer (score 47):

Thank you @naoufal.
Finally I am able to display markers on map for react native IOS.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0,
          }}
        >
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324}}
            title={"title"}
            description={"description"}
         />
      </MapView>
 </View>
```

For map and container styles, I have used following styles:

```
 var styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
    map: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    }
});
```

I have referred following link:
[React native IOS- Display Markers on map](https://medium.com/@gurusundesh/getting-started-with-react-native-mapview-5e0bd73aa602#.qzh30g32c)

Answer (score 8):

```
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

<View>
    <MapView
    style={styles.mapStyle}
    initialRegion={{
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
    >
        <Marker coordinate = {{latitude: 37.78825,longitude: -122.4324}}
         pinColor = {"purple"} // any color
         title={"title"}
         description={"description"}/>
    </MapView>
</View>
```

Comment: For android, but pelase do basic setup to render Map first.

Comment: Consider  explain your answer to question owner

Comment: @MuratAslan I didn't get you. Do you want me to explain the answer?

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a dynamic (e.g., from API), rather than hardcoded coordinates; here's the copy/paste snippet from one of the screens automatically generated by `Expo CLI`, included `React Hooks`:

```
import axios from "axios";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { Text, View } from "../components/Themed";

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://API_URL...",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer MY_TOKEN_ABC123...`,
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setMarkers(response.data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []); // "[]" makes sure the effect will run only once.

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Tab Two</Text>
      <MapView style={styles.map}>
        {markers &&
          markers.map((marker: any, index: number) => (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: marker.location[1],
                longitude: marker.location[0],
              }}
              title={marker.title}
              description={marker.description}
            />
          ))}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // Add your styles here...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated code - 2020 | React Native 0.63

```
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
<MapView
    style={styles.mapStyle}
    region={{
        latitude: this.state.mapLat,
        longitude: this.state.mapLong,
        latitudeDelta: 0.001663,
        longitudeDelta: 0.002001,
            }}
        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
>
    <Marker
        coordinate={{latitude: 51.5078788, longitude: -0.0877321}}
    >
    </Marker>
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/276), it's not exposed yet. You won't be able to use the web-React package either, React Native doesn't work like that.

Two suggestions:

1. Wait for the above issue to be resolved to get a proper API
2. Try and use WebView to link to a Google Map with an annotation

I'm not actually certain whether #2 is possible though.

Comment: After using #2 , I think the best way is #1... so I will wait. Thank you~

Comment: MapView now supports annotations.  I've added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

````
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation //to show user current location when given access
          loadingEnabled //to show loading while map loading
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
              latitude,
              longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        >
        {

             locations && locations.map((location, index) => {
                   const {
                       coords: { latitude, longitude }
                          } = location;
                                return (
                                    <MapView.Marker
                                        key={index}
                                        coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
                                        title={"title"}
                                        description={"address"}
                                        // onPress={this.onMarkerPress(location)}
                                    />
                                )
                            })
                        }
      </MapView>
 </View>```
````

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

```
map: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
}
```

});

"dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-maps": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git"
  },

```
Try using this. Hope it helps to mark for many locations. Happy Coding.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @zia_qureshi. Finally I am able to display markers on map for react native android.

```js
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";

const App = () => {
  const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 51.5078788,
    longitude: -0.0877321,
    latitudeDelta: 0.009,
    longitudeDelta: 0.009
  });

  return (
    <MapView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      region={region}
      onRegionChangeComplete={region => setRegion(region)}
    >
      <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 51.5078788, longitude: -0.0877321 }} />
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Before code added needed install and configuration ( react-native-maps )