# Is it possible to have react-native-maps subtitle on marker?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

Is it possible to put a subtitle on react-native-maps marker?

I am not seeing anything in the documentation stating this is allowed but when I google search I am seeing a number of people adding in the "subtitle" attribute to the  tag.

I am looking for something like this:

```
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={marker.coordinates ? marker.coordinates : {}}
            key={key}
            title={marker.name}
            subtitle={marker.subTitle}
            pinColor={"#0000FF"}
          />
```

When I try to hard code in a subtitle name nothing populates. The title is populating fine. Is the subtitle attribute depreciated?

References:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4656

[How do I set a marker in MapView of React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412753/how-do-i-set-a-marker-in-mapview-of-react-native)

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md

Comment: so that's a no. It would be the description that I could use as the subtitle. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom marker but for those looking, there is no subtitle option, only the description which works out just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add an image like this instead of Avatar trying to put a p-type tag

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxYUB.png)